# Lambda return of value without capture

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, clang++, icc

This follows from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37403984/1460794).

The following program compiles on gcc and icc, but fails to compile on VS and clang:

```
template <typename Y>
auto add_value(Y y)
{
    const short z{9};
    return [y](auto x)
    {
        return z;
    };
}

int main()
{
    add_value(2);
}
```

[image: godbolt example]
Flags were: `-std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -Wshadow -pedantic -pthread`

Which is correct? I suppose gcc is correct here? But I would prefer for this to fail.

Comment: You can paste the link to the *godbolt* instead of screenshot.

Comment: clang compiles it if you change it to `static const z{9};` is it an ODR-use issue?

Comment: Yes, seems like an ODR issue.

Comment: clang compiles it if you change `return z;` to `return +z;`, or if you explicitly specify the return type of the lambda.